# Open URxvt tab with shift-down, not with ctrl-t

Tags: debian, fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, urxvt

On Debian, <kbd>Shift+Down</kbd> in URxvt opens new tab.  But recently I started using another machine with Fedora, and here it has no effect; here <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> does that.  But neither one works on both, so I'm doomed to think of where I am.  Plus, I need <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> in some programs (Vim, MOC...).

Inspired by a [document on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/rxvt-unicode), I tried to add `URxvt.keysym.Shift-Down: perl:tabbedex:new_tab` to [my ~/.XDefaults,](https://github.com/AloisMahdal/mydots/blob/master/dotfiles.config/Xlib/global.Xdefaults) but that did not have effect.  (But even if it *did* work, I'm not sure if it would release <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> for other use.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to etherfish for pointers.  I have done some more research:

Turns out that this has been broken by [an RFE](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=510944), which introduced [first version of another patch](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rxvt-unicode.git/commit/?id=cc6a713b29910a54c4df9b84f160340440fc2b7a), which enabled S-down/up to *scroll one line*, thus broke the tabbing.

Later this has been addressed few times (e.g. by editing the patch and trying to change that to C-up/down), but that [was not really accepted](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=667980) so currently the situation is not solved, save for adding C-T, presumably as a hotfix (... better than *no shortcut at all*).

I have posted this as [bug against Fedora](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1096791)

So what can we do now?

- Wait for Fedora maintainers to fix the problem (or propose
  another patch).
- Build urxvt yourself from upstream.
- Use different version of tabbed, like tabbedex.
- Use local copy of `tabbed`, adding a third shortcut that works on
  both distros (either add that to ~/.urxvt or edit the system-wide file).

**Update:** Awesome, about a day later, [patch to the bug](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rxvt-unicode.git/commit/?id=848abd4d7a5ebc879ffcd7bf535311417be4380e) is already submitted and on its way to release.  Patches that broke this on Fedora are being removed so that S-Down will soon work again.  Thanks, Fedora devs!

Answer (score 3):

The ArchWiki comments are describing a different tab implementation for rxvt-unicode called "tabbedex". If you look closely, you'll notice that it's a separate package. If you want to try it out, grab the Perl source and shove it in `${HOME}/.urxvt/ext` (see the `perl-lib` config item in `rxvt-unicode(1)`).

The package maintainers in Fedora appear to have decided to include this distro-custom patch:

- http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rxvt-unicode.git/tree/rxvt-unicode-tabbed-newterm.patch

`keysym 0x74`, BTW, is <kbd>t</kbd>. You can supersede the system tabbed Perl extension by putting a copy of `/usr/lib/urxvt/perl/tabbed` from a Debian machine into `~/.urxvt/ext` on your Fedora machine or simply replacing the system copy.

Honestly, what prompted the Fedora patch? I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks for pointers. However, using Debian's `tabbed` only removes the Ctrl+T, so I end up with no shortcut at all.

Comment: You're right; I didn't realize the shift+up/down in the fedora build was hardwired in. Have you considered writing a patch for rxvt-unicode upstream making the feature a command-line - or at least, X resources option?

Comment: see my update: Fedora devs responded with great speed, and removed the patches that broke the original, upstream-like behavior.

Comment: Fantastic news! Congratulations.